# box2d strange loop (objective-c, cocos2d, box2d)

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

i was reading a tutorial from ray wenderlich website and i found this loop :

```
for(b2Body *b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {
```

so here, `b` is overwritten? i find this a bit strange

and here's the code :

```
for(b2Body *b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {    
        if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
            CCSprite *ballData = (CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();
            ballData.position = ccp(b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO,
                                    b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
            ballData.rotation = -1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle());
        }        
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, b is overwritten.  But b is just a pointer into a linked list of b2Body objects.  The whole purpose of b is to point to each b2Body in the list, one at a time.

Comment: thanks rob, okay, if we compare this to `for (var i=0; i<my_var.length; i++)` the second parameter is checking something, whereas here i'm not sure to understand what does the second argument, ...

Comment: It's checking for the null pointer that terminates the list.  Check out this article about linked lists: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/LinkedListBasics.pdf